# nunjucks macro to change a class

Tags: javascript, macros, nunjucks

What would be the correct way to use macros in nunjucks to change the class in an include?

For example, I have an include for a banner image, the client would like a different image on each page so would I be able to do something along the lines of:

```
  <section id="subheader" class="{{subHeader}}"></section>
```

Then create an array:

```
var subHeader = ["pic1", "pic2", "pic3"];
```

The bit I am unsure of is how do I get each page to take a specific picture? Something like "if file is called page1 use 0 in the array"?

Thanks for your help!

My backup plan is to just create different includes if that seems easier than setting this up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was needed:

```
{% if pg2 %}
<section id="subheader" class="subHeader banner2">
</section>
{% elseif pg3 %}
<section id="subheader" class="subHeader banner3">
</section>
{% else pg4 %}
<section id="subheader" class="subHeader banner4">
</section>
```

Then set each page to be the relevant name

```
{% set pg2 = true %} 

#skills
```